# gannt chart with 3 values

Tags: excel, charts, excel-formula

I want to create a gannt chart with 3rd value. Below is the data I have and the gantt chart I created. I would like to plot the expected as well on the graph. Any help is greatly appreciated.
[image: Data]

[image: gannt]

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use the error bars and completed the Chart.